# Accessing C array from another view controller in objective C/iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, arrays

I have a C array `val[6]` that I'm using to store a group of double values in an objective-C ViewController class (we'll call it ClassA) for an iPad application. I need to access this array from another ViewController (we'll call it ClassB). Apparently I'm not allowed to make the array a `@property`, so instead I made a getter method that just gets one value within the array:

```
-(double)getVal:(int)index{
    return val[index];
}
```

and I call it in my other method within a for loop in ClassB:

```
double newVal[6];
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    newVal[i] = [obj getVal:i];
```

where obj is an object I instantiated of type ClassA. Kinda clunky, I know, but I thought it would serve its purpose well enough. Unfortunately, `newVal[]` is being populated with 0s and I can't figure out why. `val[]` is instantiated in the .h file of ClassA and populated in a method that is called every time the program is run before the getter method is ever called:

```
-(IBAction)intervalButton:(id)sender{
    //sum the previous time values
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        sum += val[i];
    //I cut some code out of this method before posting it, 
    //so the conditions under which val is populated might not 
    //make sense, but I really just wanted display how I was setting the values of val.
    if(count < 5){
        val[count] = number - sum;
        count++;
    }else
        val[count] = number - sum;
}
```

Why isn't my array in ClassB being populated? Is it an issue with scope (ie my array gets populated within that method but not outside of it) or is it a problem with the way I'm trying to get the values from ClassA?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using a C array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `obj` is either nil or has not in fact had any values placed in its array yet. A moment of debugging will easily tell you which is the case.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what's going on- I'm instantiating a new ClassA object ("obj") in the .h file of ClassB, but it's not the same object of ClassA which has had its methods called and had operations performed on its variables. But now the question becomes, how do I access modified properties from a class if I can only create separate objects of that class?